# Cmd curl data with variable from file not working

Tags: cmd

So I have this code:

```
set /p RE_=<u.txt & curl -d data=%RE_% -d pc=%USERDOMAIN% -d user=%USERNAME% https://somewebsite.com
```

And it just doesn't work.
I have no idea why.
This is the result I am getting:
DESKTOP nktfh %RE_%

Comment: "bash"? `cmd.exe` has nothing whatsoever to do with bash.

Comment: That was a mistake sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cmd` interpreter evaluates compound statements the same way it evaluates parenthetical code blocks.  When you have:

```js
command1 args & command2 args
```

... any variables in that entire line are expanded before the commands are executed.  And thus, if you do...

```js
set "var1=value" & echo The value of var1 is %var1%
```

... you'll see at the time `%var1%` is expanded, it doesn't yet have a value.  You should either move your `curl` command to a new line, or use delayed expansion.  See `setlocal /?` and `set /?` in a cmd console for more information -- particularly the section of `set /?` which begins, *"Finally, support for delayed environment variable expansion has been added."*